# nginx passenger serving every request (*.subdomain.domain.com), even which is not there in nginx.conf file

Tags: ruby, nginx, dns

So when i m hitting app1.domain.com it giving me result(login page) however
when i m trying (something.domain.com) it is still showing me login page (which it shoudnt)

my DNS redirection is as below 
*.domainname.com my-ip

```
cat nginx.conf
user  alpha alpha;
worker_processes  4;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
passenger_root /home/user/apps/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.45;
passenger_ruby /home/user/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.5@user/ruby;

include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;
keepalive_timeout  65;
sendfile        on;
client_max_body_size 10m;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  app1.domain.com;
    root /home/user/apps/project1/current/public;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env staging2;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  app2.domain.com;
    root /home/user/apps/project2/current/public;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env staging;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  app3.domain.com;
    root /home/user/apps/project3/current/public;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env staging;
    }
 include /opt/nginx/conf/sites-enabled/*.conf;
}
```

/opt/nginx/conf/sites-enabled/app4.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  app4.domain.com;
    root /home/user/apps/project4/current/public;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env staging;
    }
```

Comment: And does it show the correct (different) results for app1.domain.com, app2.domain.com etc?

Comment: yes it is showing correct result for app1 and app2 and for others it is taking random app

Comment: Okay, can you try to make the test smaller, like having just ONE subdomain and just ONE app and just ONE server block in your *.conf files (and/or unlink from sites-enabled)? Then restart nginx, watch the log while navigating to the pages and paste some log output. Also, by "something.domain.com" do you mean "app1/app2/app3" or literally "something". Please give example (best: edit your question). thanks